# How can I make this event slider work?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to let this event slider work

I have made some requirements for this slider.

Requirements:

- On click of the left and right arrow or one day in the day slider need to change the slide.
- The days that are outdated need to get the class outdated automated
- The slide that is current at the slide needs to have the class active
- The day that is current at the slide needs to have the class active
- A nice transition with the text in the slide fade in into the slides

I edited some code already. Let me know what you think

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnJ8v.jpg

JS:

```
var mySlide = document.getElementsById('event-slider');
var slideArray = [slide-one, slide-two, slide-three, slide-four, slide-five]
var slideIndex = 1;

var currentDay = document.getElementsById('day-slider');
var dayArray = [day-one, day-two, day-three, day-four, day-five, day-six, day-seven, day-eight, day-nine, day-ten, day-eleven, day-twelve]
var dayIndex = 1;



// This function replaces classes from the slides and days.


function changeslide() {
    mySlide.setAttribute("class", slideArray[slideIndex]);
    slideIndex++;

    currentDay.setAttribute("class", slideArray[dayIndex]);
    dayIndex++


    if (slideIndex > 4) { slideIndex = 0; }
    if (dayIndez > 4) { dayIndex = 0; }
}



    // This function checks of the day date is outdated.

    function checkDate() {
        var dateString = document.getElementById('day-slider').value;
        var myDate = new Date(dateString);
        var today = new Date();
        if (myDate > today) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    if (checkDOB = false) {
        $(dayArray[dayIndex]).addClass("outdated");
    }

    if (checkDOB = true) {
        $(dayArray).addClass("current-day");
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">


        <div class="row">

            <div class="row row-margin-lg">
                <h1 class="italic add-margin-left">
                    <b> Evenementen
                        <span class="decathlon-blue"> per winkel </b>
                    </span>
                </h1>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="row-margin-slider" <div class="row">

            <div class="row navigation-arrows-slider">

                <div class="col-6">
                    <button class="left-arrow" onclick="changeslide">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <button class="right-arrow" onclick="changeslide">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row slideshow-container" id="event-slider">

            <div class="row slide-one" id="slide-one" style="display: flex">

                <div class="col-8 left-col-slider">

                    <h2 class="titel-slider uppercase italic"> Decathlon wielerweek </h2>
                    <h3 class="ondertitel-slider"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat nulla a nisi volutpat,
                        eget rhoncus velit molestie. Maecenas eget luctus lorem. Phasellus suscipit augue erat. </h3>
                    <a class="link-slider"> Lees meer ></a>

                    <div class="row lower-info-slider">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="location-slider">
                                <b>
                                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Apeldoorn</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="catogory-slider">
                                <b>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>Wielrennen</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 right-col-slider">
                    <div class="day"> 28 </div>
                    <div class="month uppercase"> feb</div>
                </div>

            </div>




            <div class="row slide-two" id="slide-two" style="display: none">

                <div class="col-8 left-col-slider">

                    <h2 class="titel-slider uppercase italic"> Decathlon wielerweek </h2>
                    <h3 class="ondertitel-slider"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat nulla a nisi volutpat,
                        eget rhoncus velit molestie. Maecenas eget luctus lorem. Phasellus suscipit augue erat. </h3>
                    <a class="link-slider"> Lees meer ></a>

                    <div class="row lower-info-slider">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="location-slider">
                                <b>
                                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Apeldoorn</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="catogory-slider">
                                <b>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>Wielrennen</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 right-col-slider">
                    <div class="day"> 28 </div>
                    <div class="month uppercase"> feb</div>
                </div>

            </div>




            <div class="row slide-three" id="slide-three" style="display: none">

                <div class="col-8 left-col-slider">

                    <h2 class="titel-slider uppercase italic"> Decathlon wielerweek </h2>
                    <h3 class="ondertitel-slider"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat nulla a nisi volutpat,
                        eget rhoncus velit molestie. Maecenas eget luctus lorem. Phasellus suscipit augue erat. </h3>
                    <a class="link-slider"> Lees meer ></a>

                    <div class="row lower-info-slider">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="location-slider">
                                <b>
                                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Apeldoorn</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="catogory-slider">
                                <b>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>Wielrennen</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 right-col-slider">
                    <div class="day"> 28 </div>
                    <div class="month uppercase"> feb</div>
                </div>

            </div>




            <div class="row slide-four" id="slide-four" style="display: none">

                <div class="col-8 left-col-slider">

                    <h2 class="titel-slider uppercase italic"> Decathlon wielerweek </h2>
                    <h3 class="ondertitel-slider"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat nulla a nisi volutpat,
                        eget rhoncus velit molestie. Maecenas eget luctus lorem. Phasellus suscipit augue erat. </h3>
                    <a class="link-slider"> Lees meer ></a>

                    <div class="row lower-info-slider">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="location-slider">
                                <b>
                                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Apeldoorn</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="catogory-slider">
                                <b>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>Wielrennen</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 right-col-slider">
                    <div class="day"> 28 </div>
                    <div class="month uppercase"> feb</div>
                </div>

            </div>



            <div class="row slide-five" id="slide-five" style="display: none">

                <div class="col-8 left-col-slider">

                    <h2 class="titel-slider uppercase italic"> Decathlon wielerweek </h2>
                    <h3 class="ondertitel-slider"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat nulla a nisi volutpat,
                        eget rhoncus velit molestie. Maecenas eget luctus lorem. Phasellus suscipit augue erat. </h3>
                    <a class="link-slider"> Lees meer ></a>

                    <div class="row lower-info-slider">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="location-slider">
                                <b>
                                    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Apeldoorn</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="catogory-slider">
                                <b>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>Wielrennen</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 right-col-slider">
                    <div class="day"> 28 </div>
                    <div class="month uppercase"> feb</div>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="row day-slider" id="day-slider">

                <div class="col-1 day-button outdated" id="day-one">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">28</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">MRT</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button outdated" id="day-two">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">16</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">OKT</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button outdated" id="day-three">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">03</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">DEC</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button" id="day-four">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">14</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">JAN</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button active" id="day-five">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">28</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">FEB</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button" id="day-six">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">05</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">MEI</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button" id="day-seven">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">15</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">MEI</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button" id="day-eight">                       
                    <h4 class="slider-day">22</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">JUN</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button" id="day-nine">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">17</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">JUL</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button" id="day-ten">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">01</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">AUG</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button" id="day-eleven">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">09</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">AUG</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 day-button" id="day-twelve">
                    <h4 class="slider-day">06</h4>
                    <h5 class="slider-month uppercase">SEPT</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*
    Theme Name: Sergino Martina
    Theme URI: local
    Description: Decathlon Testcase 
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Sergino Martina
*/

/*------------------------------------*\
    ROWS
\*------------------------------------*/

.row-padding-sm
{
    padding: 25px 0px;
}

.row-padding-md
{
    padding: 50px 0px;
}

.row-padding-lg
{
    padding: 100px 0px;
}

.white
{
    background: #fff;
}

.light-gray
{
    background: #fafafa;
}

.gray
{
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

.row-margin-lg {

    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom:50px;

}

.remove-margin-sm {

    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-right: 25px;

}



/*------------------------------------*\
    COLORS
\*------------------------------------*/


.decathlon-blue {

color: #0082C3;

}

/*------------------------------------*\
    ANIMATION Section 1 - homepage
\*------------------------------------*/

    /* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
    @-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
    @keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }


.fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

.one {

    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;

    /* background image from colomn 1*/
    background-image: url(../IMG/voetbal-bg.jpg);
    background-color: #cccccc; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.two {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
    animation-delay: 0.8s;

    /* background image from colomn 2*/
    background-image: url(../IMG/kamperen-bg.jpg);
    background-color: #cccccc;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.three {
     -webkit-animation-delay: 1.6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.6s;
    animation-delay: 1.2s;

    /* background image from colomn 3*/
    background-image: url(../IMG/vechtsport-bg.jpg);
    background-color: #cccccc;  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}

.four {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2.0s;
    animation-delay: 1.6s;

    /* background image from colomn 4*/
    background-image: url(../IMG/fietsen-bg.jpg);
    background-color: #cccccc;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }


  * {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }


.box {
    /*---make a basic box for sport catogories ---*/    
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    padding: 40px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}


  .img-item {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
}


  .img-item img {
    max-width: 100%;

    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }


  .img-item:hover img {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  .fade-in-2 {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:3s;
    animation-duration:3s;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    TEXTSTYLES
\*------------------------------------*/


.titel {

    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;

}


.ondertitel {

    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;

}


.uppercase {

    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.h5, h5 {

    font-size: 1.15rem;

}

.h6, h6 {

    font-size: 1rem;

}

.rotateText {
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);

    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);

    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);

    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-2deg);

    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.3);
}

.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Buttons
\*------------------------------------*/


.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg {
    padding: 3px 63px 4px 20px;
    margin: 28px 0px 0px 130px;
    color: black;
    background-image: url(../IMG/button.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg:hover {

    background-image: url(../IMG/button-hover.png);
    background-color: transparent;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;    

}



a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    CTA
\*------------------------------------*/


.padding-cta {

    padding: 20px 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;

}


.cta-bg-one {
    background-image: url(../IMG/CTA-bg.jpg);
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 0.01pt solid black;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    Slider
\*------------------------------------*/

.slideshow-container {

    border: solid 0.1pt;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    margin-top: -320px;

}

.row-margin-slider {

    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.slide-one {

    padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-image: url(../SLIDER/EVENTS/1.jpg);
    background-color: #cccccc;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}


.slide-two {

    padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-image: url(../SLIDER/EVENTS/2.jpg);
    background-color: #cccccc;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

.slide-three {

    padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-image: url(../SLIDER/EVENTS/3.jpg);
    background-color: #cccccc;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

.slide-four {

    padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-image: url(../SLIDER/EVENTS/4.jpg);
    background-color: #cccccc;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

.slide-five {

    padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-image: url(../SLIDER/EVENTS/5.jpg);
    background-color: #cccccc;   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}



.day {

    font-size: 180px;
    margin-top: -45px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
}

.month {

    font-size: 140px;
    margin-top: -90px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-weight: 200;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-style: italic;

}


.ondertitel-slider {

    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 200px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;

}

.titel-slider {

    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;

}

.link-slider {

    color: white !important;

}

.left-col-slider {

    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-top:100px;
}

.right-col-slider {

    margin-top: 70px;

}

.day-slider {

    margin-left: -15px;
    width: 1125px;

}


.day-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
}

.day-button:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 33px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 33px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 33px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

}

.day-button:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #0000002a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0000002a;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #0000002a;

}

.active {
        box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px white, 0 0px 0px 0px white, 12px 0 12px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.1), -15px 0 14px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.1);
        z-index: 999;

}


.thin-border{
    border: solid black 0.1pt;
}

.add-margin-left{

    margin-left:15px;
}

.outdated {

    opacity: 0.3;


}

.slider-day {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0082C3;
}

.slider-month {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #0082C3;
}

.lower-info-slider {
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.link-slider {
    font-size: 19px;
}

.location-slider {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #0082C3;
}

.catogory-slider {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #0082C3;
    margin-left:-15px;
}

.current-day {

    background-color: #0082C3;
    color: white;


}

/*------------------------------------*\
    Icons
\*------------------------------------*/

.fa, .fas {

    font-weight: 900;
    margin-right: 5px;

}

.right-arrow {

    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-left: 490px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 16px rgba(39,38,52,0.3);

}


.row.navigation-arrows-slider {

    margin-top: 220px;

}

.left-arrow {

    margin-left: -30px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 16px rgba(39,38,52,0.3);
}

.left-arrow {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.right-arrow {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code???

Comment: We need code here, not images.

Comment: Yes, I added the code. It is my first asking a question on stackoverflow.
My bad. @TakitIsy

Comment: Yes, I added the code. It is my first asking a question on stackoverflow.
My bad. @ לבני מלכה

Comment: Your JS code can't work. `document.getElementsById()` is NOT a function. You may want to use `document.getElementsByClassName()` instead.

Comment: There are wrong closing tags in your HTML as well. Examples: `<b> Evenementen
                        <span class="decathlon-blue"> per winkel </b>
        </span>` Why is the closing `</b>` before the closing `</span>` ? `<h5 class="slider-month uppercase">MRT</h4>` Here, `</h4>` should be `</h5>`.

Comment: Please, take the time to create a snippet using the [<>] button when you edit your post. Much of the errors will be either shown in red (for the HTML), or displayed in the console (for the JS) when trying to run your code.